# Error handling of csv upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

I have this import method in my active record which I use to import the csv file. I want to know how to do the error handling of this in the active record.

```
class SheetEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :task
  validate :project_and_task_should_be_active

  def self.import(csv_file)
    attributes = [:user_id, :project_id, :task_id, :date, :time_spent, :comment]
    errors=[]
    output = {}
    i=0
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true, converters: :date).with_index do |row,j|
      entry_hash= row.to_hash
      entry_hash['Project'] = SheetProject.where("name= ?" , entry_hash['Project']).pluck(:id)
      entry_hash['Task'] = SheetTask.where("name= ?" , entry_hash['Task']).pluck(:id)
      entry_hash['Date'] =  Time.strptime(entry_hash['Date'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      entry_hash['Time (Hours)'] = entry_hash['Time (Hours)'].to_f
      firstname = entry_hash['User'].split(" ")[0]
      lastname = entry_hash['User'].split(" ")[1]
      entry_hash['User'] = User.where("firstname=? AND lastname=?",firstname,lastname).pluck(:id)
      entry_hash.each do |key,value|
        if value.class == Array
          output[attributes[i]] = value.first.to_i
        else
          output[attributes[i]] = value
        end
        i += 1
      end
      entry=SheetEntry.new(output)
      entry.editing_user = User.current
      entry.save!
    end      
  end


  def project_and_task_should_be_active
    errors.add(:sheet_project, "should be active") unless  sheet_project.active?
    errors.add(:sheet_task, "should be active") if sheet_task && !sheet_task.active?
  end
end
```

I want to know how to show the error if there is a `nil` object returned for either `entry_hash['Project']` or `entry_hash['Task']`  or for any of the fields in the csv.

For example: If the user had entered the wrong project or wrong task or wrong date. I want the error to be shown along with the line no and stop the uploading of the csv. Can someone help?

Comment: You can always use `.nil?` which returns true or false

Comment: you might want to look at the `SmarterCSV` gem.
https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use `begin` and `rescue` statements to handle errors in any ruby classes.

You can use the `rescue` block to return the Exception `e` back to the caller.
However, you cannot call `errors.add` method to add error because `#errors` is an instance method which is not accessible inside class method `self.import`.

```
def self.import(csv_file)
  begin
    attributes = [:user_id, :project_id, :task_id, :date, :time_spent, :comment]
    errors=[]
    output = {}
    i=0
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true, converters: :date).with_index do |row,j|
      ...
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    return "Error: #{e}"
  end
end
```

Comment: you can store the return value of that method in an instance variable on your controller's action `@import_response = SheetEntry.import(csv_file)`, then just use `if..else` in the view `<% if @import_response == true %> <p>import succeeded</p> <% else %> <p>Error <%= @import_response %> </p>`

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so other with similar issue can find the solution as well.